# How to do different actions for a different Extras sent to an activity?

Tags: java, android, class, object, android-activity

I have an activity which shows information  about an object (TextView name, ImageView image etc) and I'm sending those data from 2 different activities, while the data are of different classes, but contain exactly the same attributes so I always can get the name or picture with the same getters. (The objects are basically the same "type" but I needed to make 2 different classes since I'm using Realm database). So in the target activity, I need to find out which class has been sent to it and then set resources to those views.

This is my attempt and I don't know if it's right (since the app is crashing in some cases and don't know if the fault is here or somewhere else so I want to make clear if this is OK). The classes are called Illusion and FavouriteIllusion and both are Parcelable so that they can be sent via Extras. This is my code:

```
final Object item = getIntent().getExtras().get("item");

    if (item.getClass() == Illusion.class) {
        Illusion illusion = (Illusion) item;

        TextView title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_title);
        title.setText(illusion.getName());

        //some more resource settings here

    } else if (item.getClass() == FavouriteIllusion.class) {
        FavouriteIllusion illusion = (FavouriteIllusion) item;

        TextView title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_title);
        title.setText(illusion.getName());

        //some more resource settings here

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply send the **class name** as **extra** then apply to your `if-else` condition in target activity:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Illusion.this, TargetActivity.class);
i.putExtra("class","Illusion");     // Do as this in FavouriteIllusion
```

In Target Activity:

```
  final Object item = getIntent().getExtras().get("item");
  String getClass = getIntent().getStringExtra("class");

    if (getClass.equals("Illusion")) {
        Illusion illusion = (Illusion) item;

        TextView title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_title);
        title.setText(illusion.getName());

        //some more resource settings here

    } else if (getClass.equals("FavouriteIllusion") {
        FavouriteIllusion illusion = (FavouriteIllusion) item;

        TextView title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_title);
        title.setText(illusion.getName());

        //some more resource settings here

    }
```

Hope this helps.